# Parallelizing a program in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working a lot with texts in Python, but im kinda new to the language and don't yet know how to employ multi-threading in Py.

My usecase is the following:

1. Single producer P (database/XML) which generates texts T_s.
2. Each of the texts in T_s could be processed independently. Processed texts compose T_p set.
3. The resulting set is written to a text-file/XML/database by a single thread S.

Data volumes are huge and all the processing couldn't keep anything except for the current data in the memory.

I would organize the process as the following:

1. Producer put the texts into Q_s queue.
2. There are a set of workers and a manager that gets texts from the queue and distributes between workers.
3. Each worker puts the processed text to the Q_p.
4. Sink process reads processed texts from Q_p and persists them.

Beyound all that *Producer* should be able to communicate that it ended reading the input data source to the manager and the sink.

**Summary.** I learned so far, that there is a nice lib/solution for each of the typical tasks in Py. Is there any for my current task?

Comment: Google gives good results on "python worker threads producer-consumer howto", including e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998520/python-threading-queue-producer-consumer-with-thread-safe

Answer (score 2):

Due to the nature of CPython (see [gil](/questions/tagged/gil)), you will need to use multiple processes rather than threads if your tasks are CPU and not I/O bound. Python comes with the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module that has everything you need to get the job done. Specifically, it has [pools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) and thread-safe [queues](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues).

In your case, you need an input and output queues that you pass to each worker and they asynchronously read from the input queue and write to the output queue. The single threaded producers/consumers just operate on their respective queues, keeping only what's necessary in memory. The only potential quirk here is that order of outputs may not correlate with the order of the inputs.

Note: you can communicate status with the [`JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) class.

Comment: Many thanks for highlighting the key aspects, that I would probably missed  myself. Found a nice primer of doing what I want based on using _multithreading_ module: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html